# Custom System.Text.Json Converter string not working

Tags: c#, .net-core, system.text.json, jsonconverter

I wrote a string custom System.Text.Json converter

```
public class TranslatableJsonConverter : JsonConverter<string>
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public TranslatableJsonConverter(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }
    public override string? Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, string value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        var request = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.Request;
        if (request is null)
        {
            writer.WriteStringValue(value);
            return;
        }
        var acceptLanguage = request.GetUserLanguage();
        writer.WriteStringValue($"KPI_FAMILY_{value}".Translate(acceptLanguage));
    }
}
```

Here, I injected the `IHttpContextAccessor` because I have to retrieve an header field to process a string property of a record dto.
Then I registered the custom converter in the following way:

```
public class ConfigureJsonOptions : IConfigureOptions<JsonOptions>
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public ConfigureJsonOptions(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }
    public void Configure(JsonOptions options)
    {
        options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new TranslatableJsonConverter(_httpContextAccessor));
    }
}

// Startup.cs
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
services.ConfigureOptions<ConfigureJsonOptions>();
```

So, I decorated the property that I'd like to process:

```
public record DriverBehaviourFamilyCountersDto
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(TranslatableJsonConverter))]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    
    public IEnumerable<BehaviourCounterDto> Behaviours { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is that I get the following exception, when serialization happens

> System.InvalidOperationException: The converter specified on
> 'Video.Analytics.DriverBehavior.Coaching.BFF.Api.Dto.Output.DriverBehaviourFamilyCountersDto.Name'
> does not derive from JsonConverter or have a public parameterless
> constructor.\r\n   at
> System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException_SerializationConverterOnAttributeInvalid(Type
> classType, MemberInfo memberInfo)\r\n   at
> System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver.GetConverterFromAttribute(JsonConverterAttribute
> converterAttribute, Type typeToConvert, MemberInfo memberInfo,
> JsonSerializerOptions options)\r\n   at
> System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver.GetCustomConverterForMember(Type
> typeToConvert, MemberInfo memberInfo, JsonSerializerOptions
> options)\r\n   at
> System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.ReflectionJsonTypeInfo`1.CreateProperty(Type typeToConvert, MemberInfo memberInfo, JsonSerializerOptions options, Boolean shouldCheckForRequiredKeyword)\r\n   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.ReflectionJsonTypeInfo`1.LateAddProperties()\r\n
> at
> System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.JsonTypeInfo.InitializePropertyCache()\r\n
> at
> System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.JsonTypeInfo.Configure()\r\n
> at
> System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.JsonTypeInfo.g__ConfigureLocked|143_0()\r\n
> at
> System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.JsonTypeInfo.EnsureConfigured()\r\n
> at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions.GetTypeInfoInternal(Type
> type, Boolean ensureConfigured, Boolean resolveIfMutable)\r\n   at
> System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.JsonTypeInfo.get_ElementTypeInfo()\r\n
> at
> System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonCollectionConverter`2.OnTryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, TCollection value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)\r\n   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.TryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter
> writer, T& value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack&
> state)\r\n   at
> System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.JsonPropertyInfo`1.GetMemberAndWriteJson(Object obj, WriteStack& state, Utf8JsonWriter writer)\r\n   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.ObjectDefaultConverter`1.OnTryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter
> writer, T value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)\r\n
> at
> System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.TryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T& value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)\r\n   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.WriteCore(Utf8JsonWriter
> writer, T& value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack&
> state)\r\n   at
> System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.WriteCoreAsObject(Utf8JsonWriter
> writer, Object value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack&
> state)\r\n   at
> System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.WriteCore[TValue](Utf8JsonWriter
> writer, TValue& value, JsonTypeInfo jsonTypeInfo, WriteStack&
> state)\r\n   at
> System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.WriteStreamAsync[TValue](Stream
> utf8Json, TValue value, JsonTypeInfo jsonTypeInfo, CancellationToken
> cancellationToken)\r\n   at
> System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.WriteStreamAsync[TValue](Stream
> utf8Json, TValue value, JsonTypeInfo jsonTypeInfo, CancellationToken
> cancellationToken)\r\n   at
> System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.WriteStreamAsync[TValue](Stream
> utf8Json, TValue value, JsonTypeInfo jsonTypeInfo, CancellationToken
> cancellationToken)\r\n   at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.SystemTextJsonOutputFormatter.WriteResponseBodyAsync(OutputFormatterWriteContext
> context, Encoding selectedEncoding)\r\n   at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|30_0[TFilter,TFilterAsync](ResourceInvoker
> invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean
> isCompleted)\r\n   at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContextSealed
> context)\r\n   at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext[TFilter,TFilterAsync](State&
> next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)\r\n   at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()\r\n---
> End of stack trace from previous location ---\r\n   at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker
> invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean
> isCompleted)\r\n   at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker
> invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)\r\n   at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker
> invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)\r\n   at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint
> endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)\r\n   at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy.AuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler.HandleAsync(RequestDelegate
> next, HttpContext context, AuthorizationPolicy policy,
> PolicyAuthorizationResult authorizeResult)\r\n   at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)\r\n   at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)\r\n   at
> Serilog.AspNetCore.RequestLoggingMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> httpContext)\r\n   at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.g__Awaited|6_0(ExceptionHandlerMiddleware
> middleware, HttpContext context, Task task)"

Could you help me please?

Comment: Did you read the error? You can't create a converter that requires parameters like this. `IHttpContextAccessor` has no meaning outside the *current* request either. You don't know if the converter is once for every request (wasteful) or just once and reused. If you want to add information to the action response, add it to the response itself

Comment: The exception text doesn't change the fact you can't pass paremeters to the constructor. Or that there's no request at all when the JSON serializer works. This isn't part of the ASP.NET Core middleware at all

Comment: It seems that the *real* problem you want to solve is to localize the response. The user language is only one way to detect the language and *not* the most common. ASP.NET Core has [localization middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization/select-language-culture?view=aspnetcore-7.0) that handles multiple strategies for selecting the language - from the browser, URL parameters, cookies. Your own localization code doesn't need to know this, it only reads the detected language. That's *not* something you do in the JSON serializer

Comment: Not really. `IHttpContextAccessor` is injected correctly inside the converter. I can retrieve my request and my headers correctly.

Comment: The error says the exact opposite `The converter specified on 'Video.Analytics.DriverBehavior.Coaching.BFF.Api.Dto.Output.DriverBehaviourFamilyCountersDto.Name' does not derive from JsonConverter or have a public parameterless constructor.`. The converter isn't created at all

Comment: I know how localization middleware works. But unfortunately I have a separate package that handle the localization and the requirement is to get the user language through `Accept-Language` header.

Comment: Which is already supported by the middleware. And the error says the converter can't be created at all, so why insist on this? Why not translate the response *in the action itself*?

Comment: Perhaps what you want is to create a [custom IStringLocalizer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization-extensibility?view=aspnetcore-7.0#localization-resources) that uses your library?

Comment: Because if I change my converter in `TranslatableJsonConverter : JsonConverter<DriverBehaviourFamilyCountersDto>` and remove the attribute above the string, I can access `HttpContext` correctly in the write method. But I would not write a custom converter for each DTO

Comment: But on the property, you can't even create the converter. If you know how the localization middleware works, why not create your own localizer? Why try something so hacky?

Comment: [Inject a service into a System.Text.Json converter](https://thomaslevesque.com/2020/08/31/inject-service-into-system-text-json-converter/) might help.  Still pretty hacky though.

Comment: Thanks @dbc. I followed that link indeed